# Is there a built in .NET exception that indicates an illegal object state?

Tags: c#, .net, exception

What exception should I throw if I encounter an illegal state - for instance, an initialization method that should only be called once being called a second time?  I don't really see any built-in exception that makes sense.  This seems like something that should be in the framework - am I not poking in the right spot?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

[InvalidOperationException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.invalidoperationexception.aspx) maybe?

> The exception that is thrown when a method call is invalid for the object's current state.

Comment: More and more people should use InvalidOperationException instead of creating new ones.

Comment: True, or at least derive from it so that catching InvalidOperationException also catches the derived one. Look at the Exceptions that derive from IOE (bottom of the MSDN) to see when it could make sense to roll your own.

Comment: it depends. You are trying to perform an Invalid Operation after all, but there are many ways to name it.

Comment: And then what would you expect if the call is always invalid no matter what state the object is in?

Comment: @Joshua
In my opinion either [System.NotSupportedException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.notsupportedexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [System.NotImplementedException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.notimplementedexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) depending on the actual context.

I consider NotSupportedException in case of a permanently "unavailable" method that should never be a valid call.
And use NotImplementedException when it is a temporary lack of implementation or is a context-dependent object state that misses the actual implementation.

Answer (score 1):

In general you should program your object in such a way *that it cannot reach an invalid state*. If you find out that your object is in an invalid state then you should throw a `SystemException` or an exception *directly derived* from `SystemException`. This is the answer to the question *in the title*.

However, the exceptional circumstance that you are *referring to* in the question text is a *user of your object* pushing it into an illegal state. In that case `InvalidOperationException` is the right exception to throw, as indicated in [this earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/259805/589259). This will avoid your object *getting* into an illegal state.

Needless to say you need to *document* how your object should be used. If your object has a long life expectancy or if it is used/shared between different objects then it is nice for a user to be able to request the current state, and to implement `ToString` to retrieve the current state as text, for instance in a debugging environment / log.

Answer (score -3):

If at all I'd say System.InvalidProgramException get nearest to what you want. What's wrong with throwing a custom exception?

Comment: IPE: "The exception that is thrown when a program contains invalid Microsoft intermediate language (MSIL) or metadata. Generally this indicates a bug in the compiler that generated the program.". Using Standard Exceptions creates consistency around the framework and third party apps.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with custom exceptions if there is nothing in the framework to support your case.  I could write a custom ArrayList, but why would I?

Comment: ok, like pYrania I don't get either why do you think this is so important? You have to write SOME code to implement ArrayList, but this cannot be compared to create a custom exception...

Comment: The point is that you should not duplicate existing functionality.  If I throw a custom exception, that is another thing that a programmer using my library has to learn.  If I follow the conventions of the framework, I allow them to leverage their existing knowledge.

Comment: Yes, but nevertheless you should write a documentation for your library. Giving that, for a user it shouldn't matter if the exception you throw is Exception1 or Exception2.

Comment: Very old thread but, to anyone interested... Of course it does matter which exception type is thrown, since C#'s exception handling mechanism is based on that. For instance: `catch (SomeException ex) { doSomeStuff(); } catch (SomeOtherException ex) { doSomeOtherStuff(); }`. But if you don't care about writing good, meaningful code, just `throw new Exception("whatever")` and be done with it.

Comment: I've been known to throw InvalidProgramException when the attempted call is utterly irrational; that is when the call "working" would imply a transform of the server persistent state that breaks key invariants. The general meaning is "The thing you are trying to do is logically invalid and if you go around the object's limitations the thing you are trying to do is still invalid." I've only ended up with a few of these, one of which the call "working" would imply remote code attestation is a solved problem, and another is an inherent race condition with another component.

Comment: Note that even though this has three downvotes, I think this is a **very helpful wrong answer**. Please do not delete, or people may be tricked into using this exception. Please do not downvote any furthher.