# What exception to throw on invalid object state?

Tags: c#, .net, exception

I always missed a built-in exception type in c# which would indicate that an object is corrupted. What do you throw in such cases?

Usually I miss it when I realize that a method, that is supposed to work on an object, would fail if the object had a certain state. In such situations I often suspect that this state probably won't be ever reached. But being defensive about it, I'd like to throw an exception just in case it will (e.g. after a future code change).

For method arguments we have `ArgumentException` so we can deny invalid parameters. But for object state? In Java I'd use `IllegalStateException`.

Of course you could argue that the methods, that are actually changing the state, could check for state correctness. And they better should, but then if they don't (say in legacy god classes)?

**Edit:**

Although `InvalidOperationException` seems to be the best fit, as the accepted answer states (and also [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/259800/is-there-a-built-in-net-exception-that-indicates-an-illegal-object-state)), please note:

It is subtle, but semantically this has a different meaning than `InvalidOperationException`. `InvalidOperationException` indicates a problem in the "protocol" of the object, which the caller has to obey (e.g. not initialized, closed already, ...). In my case the caller did nothing wrong, it's the object that is broken. I would like to transport exactly that message.

Example:

```
switch(this._someType) {
  case SomeType.A: doSomething(); break;
  case SomeType.B: doSomethingElse(); break;
  /*...*/
  default:
    // Unexpected type! Someone introduced a new type and didn't update this.
    throw new IllegalStateException("Unknown type "+this._someType); 
}
```

Comment: Generally, `InvalidOperationException`.

Comment: Please see my comment to Matthew Watsons answer about `InvalidOperationException`.

Comment: A better example for the overall principle might be trying to `Add` an item to a dictionary-ish object in which an internal linked list has become corrupted (e.g. due to illegitimate multi-threaded use).  Normally, an `InvalidOperatonException` thrown from an `Add` method would indicate that an item with the indicated key had already been added, and code which catches such an exception would likely expect that to be true.  I would posit that it's very bad to throw an exception of a type that has associated expectations when the state of an object doesn't fit them.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You should throw [`InvalidOperationException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.invalidoperationexception.aspx) to indicate that an object has invalid state.

From the MSDN documentation (linked above):

> The exception that is thrown when a method call is invalid for the object's current state.

Comment: Maybe it's subtle, but semantically this has a different meaning. `InvalidOperationException` indicates a problem in the "protocol" of the object, which the caller has to obey (e.g. not initialized, closed already, ...). In my case the caller did nothing wrong, it's the object that is *broken*. I would like to transport exactly that message.

Comment: @IgorLankin In that case, you would probably want `Trace.Assert(someConditionThatMustBeTrue)` Because if your code is broken, there's no sensible exception you could throw that it would ever make sense to catch. It would effectively be a `MyCodeIsBroken` exception!

Comment: (Another thought) You should still use `InvalidOperationException`, since that's what you're supposed to use for this in .Net (even given your distinction, which I fully understand) - but you can say in the exception message exactly what the problem is, so you don't lose any information.

Comment: I personally think `InvalidOperationException` is overused and too much of catch-all, but it *is* what's commonly used for this kind of purpose in .NET.  You could define your own exception type too, but I have to wonder what circumstances you're anticipating that would unavoidably put your object into a corrupt state in the first place.  Maybe some more information would shed some light?  Without much context, my first reaction is that the effort would be better spent on preventing that condition rather than responding to it.

Comment: Right, assertions might be the solution in many cases.

Comment: @MatthewWatson: I think the problem with `InvalidOperationException` may be illustrated by example: suppose the `Add` method for a non-threadsafe `Dictionary`-ish type finds a cycle in a linked list of nodes associated with a hash value.  Code which calls `foo.Add(bar)` and catches `InvalidOperationException` would likely expect that `foo` is an internally-consistent structure to which `bar` has already been added, when in reality it may be a broken data structure to which `bar` was never added.

Comment: @supercat If I see an `InvalidOperationException` I will assume that the state of the object involved is probably invalid. For example, if you call `MoveNext` on an iterator to a modified collection you will get an `InvalidOperationException` which tells you that the iterator is mince. Not having a .Net exception to express "invalid program logic" conditions is a pain, but that's what we have to deal with. I like the Code Contracts exceptions (e.g. as thrown by `Contract.Assume(mustBeTrue)`) but alas they don't fire in release builds *unless* you turn on FULL runtime checking.

Answer (score 2):

The closest analogue I can figure as of .Net 2.0 [something better may have been added since] would be `ObjectDisposedException`, which indicates that an object *has been placed into a permanently-invalid state*.  Such an exception may be considered "unexpected", but that's a good thing, since the condition it is indicating would be likewise unexpected.  Further, if a method on an object discovers that its state is invalid it should, after capturing as much information about the object's state as may be helpful for trouble-shooting, deliberately place the object into a permanently-invalid state so that all future operations on it (other than perhaps requests to extract the information that was captured for trouble-shooting purposes) will throw an exception.

Because of the strong association between `IDisposable` and `ObjectDisposedException`, it may be better to define a new exception type which may or may not inherit from `ObjectDisposedException`.  Arguably, `ObjectDisposedException` should have been derived from an `ObjectInvalidatedException`, which should also have `CorruptObjectDiscoveredException` and `CorruptObjectInvalidatedException` [the former being thrown by the first method which finds the corruption, and the latter by subsequent method calls on the same object], but I'm not sure it really matters.

What's most important I think is to ensure that code which has reason to believe that an object may be in a corrupt state expressly invalidate the object.  Some people have suggested that methods which discover unexpected problems should attempt to bring down the whole system.  I strongly disagree with that philosophy.  If a method puts an object into what is supposed to be a temporarily-corrupted state and then exits via an exception before the object's state can be fixed, it should invalidate the object completely rather than leaving it corrupted.  If after stack unwinding the system can't function without the now-invalidated object, it will come crashing down in short order (a better alternative than functioning with corrupted state).  If, however, the process of unwinding the stack causes the corrupt object to be abandoned (e.g. someone tried to load a document from a file of the wrong type, causing an exception within a method called by `LoadDocument`), the fact that the now-abandoned object was corrupt may be useful information for understanding why an exception was thrown, but may carry no averse implications for the overall health of the system.

Comment: Well if I saw an `ObjectDisposedException` I would be very suprised if it wasn't thrown because an operation was called on a disposed object...

Comment: @MatthewWatson: Thus my recommendation that a custom exception may be better.  I take the view that exception handling is (or should be) concerned less with the particulars of what happened than with the resulting system state.  Code which gets an `InvalidOperationException` when adding something to a dictionary-ish collection may expect that when the exception is caught, the collection will contain an item with the given key.  If that isn't true, the method shouldn't throw that exception.  Operations which fail with objects in unexpected states should cause unexpected exceptions.

Comment: I understand, but unfortunately unexpected custom exception types can be a right pain when they occur server-side and the client side can't deserialise it. You can end up totally losing the exception and just getting deserialization-related exceptions on the client, which makes it really hard to work out what's going on (as I found out fairly recently... ;) As to the dictionary example - I don't really understand why you'd think that the collection would contain something with that key. You should get an `ArgumentException` if that was the case.

Comment: (Continued) However, I must stress that I would really have preferred there to be a built-in `ProgramLogicException` that we could throw, and additionally an `Assert.That(someConditionShouldBeTrue)` method that would throw it.

Comment: @MatthewWatson: Exception handling is by its nature an icky business; the pattern of using the type of a thrown exception as a means of deciding who should catch it may have justifiable in the design of a language like C++ which has no "special" class types hard-coded into the language, but it has limitations which Java and .NET have failed to address.  Although `ObjectDisposedException` may not accurately describe what caused a failure, it is more accurate than any other exception I can think of in describing the state of the object afterward.

Comment: @MatthewWatson: The `ProgramLogicException` exception concept may be reasonable, though not wonderfully so, since it provides no clue as to what a caller should do.  Sorry I misremembered the exception thrown in the particular case of `Dictionary.Add`, though I recall there are other places in the framework where `IOE` indicates that the object can't perform the precise requested operation, but is (typically) in a state where it might perform some others, and the caller might have an idea as to why the operation failed.

Comment: What do you mean by "it provides no clue as to what a caller should do". Surely by its very nature, a program logic failure can't provide such a clue? If some piece of internal logic that should be true, isn't - then what can you really say about that condition other than "oops - something went wrong"? Saying "the oogleflip couldn't be deflexified" is meaningful only to the implementation code. But you can at least attach a human-readable message to it.

Comment: I realise that there are two different kinds of situations that I'm talking about - the case where the caller tries to use an object which is in an invalid state for that use (e.g. `MoveNext()` on iterator to modified collection). That is caused by errors in the calling code. The other case is where something "impossible" has happened - there's a bug in the implementing code (e.g. that list I just put something into is now empty wtf). My `ProgramLogicException` was for the second case, and for the first case I still think `InvalidOperationException` is ok.

Comment: @MatthewWatson: In many cases, the very fact that a method call exits via exception implies that something, somewhere, is not in the state that would be expected if the call had returned normally.  The $50,000 question is *what* is in an unexpected state.  In many cases, the proper course of action is to jettison corrupt objects, crashing if and only if the program can't continue without them.  If a program-logic problem occurs while loading a document from a file, for example, the corruption is limited to the partially-constructed document, and code can get by without that document, ...

Comment: ...then failure to load the document should not disrupt the remainder of the application.  On the other hand, if the program-logic error occurred because of a data structure that was shared by many documents, that represents a rather different situation.  Unfortunately, existing error-handling mechanisms do little to distinguish between them.